# How to draw text in NPAPI plugin CGContextRef?

Tags: plugins, cgcontext, drawtext

I want to draw text in the NPAPI plugin CGContextRef, but i don’t know to make it work.
I get the CGContext Ref as follow:

```
int16_t NPP_HandleEvent(NPP instance, void* event)
{
    int16_t iRet = 0; 
    PluginObject *obj = (PluginObject *)instance->pdata;
    NPCocoaEvent *cocoaEvent = (NPCocoaEvent *)event;
    switch(cocoaEvent->type)
    {
    case NPCocoaEventDrawRect:
        obj->m_NPContext = CGContextRetain(cocoaEvent->data.draw.context);
        DrawSealOnContext(obj->m_NPContext, obj->m_pstSealAPInfo);
        iRet = 1;
        break; 
    default:
        iRet = 0;
    break;
    }
    return iRet;
}
```

In function DrawSealOnContext, I want to draw an Ellipse and some text in the window. the function as follow:

```
int DrawSealOnContext(CGContextRef contextRef, PSEAL_APPEARANCE_INFO pstSealAPInfo)
{
    // draw ellipses 
    CGRect rect = {2, 25, 146, 100};
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(contextRef, [NSColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(contextRef);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(contextRef, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(contextRef, kCGPathStroke);

    // draw text
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, [NSColor blueColor].CGColor);
    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
    NSDictionary * attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:paragraphStyle
                                forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
    NSString * mystr = @“hello\n and";
    NSRect strFrame = { { 0, 0 }, { 150, 150 } };
    [mystr drawInRect:strFrame withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

I can get the ellipse on the screen, but the text doesn’t show up?

I also try this:

```
// draw text
CGContextShowText(contextRef, "hello", 5);
```

It doesn’t work either.

what’s wrong with my program, really appreciate your 
answers.

Comment: While it's not the issue with your code, note that you should *not* be storing the context, as you are in the first code block. In the CG+Cocoa model combination, the context you are given is only guaranteed to be valid during the HandleEvent call, and it may change from call to call. If you try to use the context you've stored any time after the function returns, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: then how can I draw Ellipse and text in that CGContext? put all code in function: int16_t NPP_HandleEvent(NPP instance, void* event) ?

Comment: I have tried put draw text code in function:int16_t NPP_HandleEvent(NPP instance, void* event), it doesn't work either. Maybe something else is wrong, or i can not draw text directly on CGContext in that way?  I tried use another function :CGContextShowTextAtPoint(contextRef, 8, 72, "hello", 6), it works. But the problem is, this function can not draw Chinese characters, it does not meet my requirement.

Comment: I need to use function :[mystr drawInRect:strFrame withAttributes:attributes]; but i don't know how to use it in my situation！

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem, with the help of this article:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/240527-setting-cgcontextref-to-the-current-context.html
The problem is that, function

```
[mystr drawInRect:strFrame withAttributes:attributes];
```

draw test in current context, but my current is not the the context "CGContextRef contextRef" i decleared. So, before i used drawInRect method, i need to set contextRef my current context.
    How to set CGContextRef to current context, please refer to the website i pasted.
    Hope this answer can solve your problem!